# С роду / сроду сто лет

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Мне сто лет с роду / сроду.`

`Я сроду / с роду собираю зелёно-голубые фантики.`

Comment: Котик, ну никак же, увы, не правильно. И если задавать вопрос, то про сроду-с_роду и отроду-от_роду. Про возраст с_роду и сроду  не говорят. И второе тоже так не говорят.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Леопольд, я дополнил ответ, посмотрите и скажите, пожалуйста, что вам нравится, а что не нравится. Поверьте, это важно. Если вам что-то не нравится, я могу дополнить, если знаю, — и вы получите то, что хотели. Всегда говорите, что вам не нравится, или принимайте ответ, если всë так. Мне важно это знать. Вам же лучше, получите самый четкий ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно слитное написание:

***Мне сто лет сроду***;

***Я сроду собираю зелёно-голубые фантики***.

Наречие ***сроду*** в значении ***никогда (ни разу в жизни)***, ***с момента рождения***, ***с момента появления/создания чего-л.*** пишется **слитно**.

---

**ДОПОЛНЕНО.**

Раздельного написания слова *с роду* не существует, так что только *сроду*. А если в первом варианте другое значение, то проще так и написать, с ***от роду***:

*Мне сто лет **от роду***.

Comment: Но в 1-м случае другое значение. Может, по аналогии с *от роду* и *отроду*?

Comment: А какое значение? Подскажите — может, дополню. Кстати, вам помог ответ на вопрос «Запятушончонка или точка с нею?» Не приняли и не оставили коммент по этому поводу.

Comment: Я указал в ответе 3 возможных значения. Какое значение у вас?

Comment: Я не понял, что Буратино написал. Как правильно, ей-богу, писать-то?

Comment: Sir, you didn't know how to properly, without the supplement. I have completed the answer, look.

Comment: Ну, ну... ну ладно-с.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, увы, не правильно.

СРОДУ - сложно с никогда, употребляется как отрицание, то есть с рождения такого ни разу не было со мной/с тобой/с ним и тп.:

> Он еще сроду не видел, что это за народ козаки. Гоголь.

> — Я твоей царской милости честно в опричниках служу и сроду еще на ослопах не бился! Толстой.

В редких исключениях можно написать С_РОДУ. Обычно, когда в связке с "с_роду моего/ своего и тп."

> — С роду моего ее не пила и пить не стану. Лесков.

Либо речь идет про приобретенные с рождения, врожденные качества, например, качества характера или тела:

> В ту пору лев был сыт, хоть с роду он свиреп. Пушкин.

> — Вот какие ноги. Обе такие, с роду. Не ходят, не живут, а — так себе... Горький.

Отроду - тоже отрицание: отродясь такого не было, в целом тоже самое, что и сроду.

От роду - говорят про возраст, но употребления числительного идет в родительному падеже. Я ста лет от роду - мне сто лет(от роду лишнее).

Либо употребляется с глаголами было или был:

> Мне был тогда тринадцатый год от роду, и я знал только русскую грамоту
> и четыре правила арифметики. Булгарин.
>
> Мать кузнеца Вакулы имела от роду не больше сорока лет. Гоголь.

Либо нужен предикат:

> Следуйте примеру этого молодого человека: ему **едва** семнадцать лет
> от роду, а он уже дает за женщин шесть рублей. Сенковский.

Либо нужна запятая или другая разбивка фраз:

> ...молодая горячая лошадь в серых яблоках, семнадцати лет от роду...
> Гоголь

То есть: Сколько вам от роду лет? - Мне? сто лет от роду!

Хотя Пушкин, Шишков писали отроду слитно, про возраст и вообще в утвердительных предложениях:

> ...а мнѣ отроду въ первый разъ случилось имѣть у себя такого постояльца. Шишков.

> Успехи мои хотя были медленны, но благонадежны, ибо на десятом году отроду я знал уже почти все то, что поныне осталось у меня в памяти, от природы слабой и которую по причине столь же слабого здоровья не дозволяли мне излишне отягощать. Пушкин.

> Троекуров отдал полную справедливость винам своего Амфитриона и искусству его повара, а Марья Кириловна не чувствовала ни малейшего замешательства или принуждения в беседе с человеком, которого видела она только во второй раз отроду.

> Петр, посылая Апраксину ордер баталии и известие о своем наименовании, пишет: «чаю, не забудешь свою пословицу: отроду впервые», притом жалуется на датчан etc.

> Отроду в первый раз Евсея назвали красавцем; ему это показалось так забавно, что он купил баранки и грыз их дорогою, улыбаясь выдумке затейливой продавщицы. Даль.

ОТРОДУ ~ **никогда** / **но** первый(второй) или **исключительный раз за всю жизнь** / при противопоставлении НО / ДА И ТО / БУДУЧИ В СТОЛЬ ЮНОМ ВОЗРАСТЕ и подобное событие не по возрасту.

> Ей отроду около ста лет; но она в полном здравии, и крепка как спартанка.

> Чтобы мне отсохнули руки и ноги, если что-нибудь когда-либо крал, выключая разве вареники с сметаною у матери, да и то еще, когда мне было лет десять отроду». Гоголь.

То есть СРОДУ - **никогда, либо то, что положено иметь с рождения.** - с рождения - соединение.

А ОТРОДУ - **никогда, то чего не положено иметь по возрасту, но случилось.** - от рода - противопоставление.